# Checking rows for identical elements

Tags: python, matrix

I need to check if there any matches in the rows of a matrix. There is a match if any of the rows contain two identical elements next to each other or are only separated by a `None`. For example

```
[[2, None, 2],
[2, None, None],
[None, None, None]]
```

would count as a match, since in the first row the two's are only separated by a 'None'. But something like

```
[[2, None, None],
[2, None, None],
[None, None, 2]]
```

would have to return `False.` The program I wrote works correctly for many cases, but there are some mistakes. I have:

```
def check_rows(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix) - 2):
            if (matrix[i][j] != None and matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+1]):
                return True

            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[i][j+1] and matrix[i][j+1] == None) and matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+2]:
                return True

            if matrix[i][j+1] != None and matrix[i][j+1] == matrix[i][j+2]:
                return True

            else:
                return False
```

But if I apply to this to

```
[[4, None, None],
[4, None, None],
[2, 2, None]]
```

I get `False` as a result, which is incorrect (the last row has a match). Also, this program must work for a matrix of any dimension. Can someone point out where my mistake is? Because I don't see it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, rather than futzing with all of those indices, I would prefer to rewrite the function in an essentially index-free way, like so:

```
import itertools

def check_rows(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        # Strip out the Nones from the row
        filtered = filter(lambda x: x is not None, row)
        # Copy the iterator for the filtered row
        f1, f2 = itertools.tee(filtered)
        # Advance the second one by one step, if possible
        try:
            next(f2)
        except StopIteration:
            # If there's nothing in the filtered row, then clearly there are
            # no duplicates. Move on to the next row.
            continue
        # Look at the elements of f1 and the corresponding "off-by-one" elements
        # of f2. If they are ever equal, we know that we have identical elements
        # adjacent to one another, so we return True early.
        if any(a == b for a, b in zip(f1, f2)):
            return True
    return False
```

Note that because this function doesn't do any explicit manipulation of indices, it pretty much has to work (and does, in fact, work) on a matrix of any size.